# how to handle git: patch does not apply

Tags: git

I have a patch file generated one year ago. (the person making the code change has left so I do not have his workspace to sync with current code. I only have a patch file showing diff at that time).

I want to add his change to the latest branch. To do that, I git apply the patch file to my workspace, it showed some files are "patch does not apply". The reason is that git cannot not find the right place to insert his change. one year ago, his change should be inserted between line X and X+1 of the file. But now, when git apply tried to do that, it found line X and X+1 has become sth. else. (because of the introduction of other code during this year).

To verify my guess, I manully removed some code of that file so that line X and line X+1 becomes the same as when patch was generateed, this time git apply did not complain this file.

My question is how to git apply an old patch?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. You don't. You study the patch to understand the intent of the change and you make your own edits.
2. You make a branch from a commit that is at the same point in time as the source that the patcher was looking at. You apply the patch, and then you merge.

However, the 'merge' step in the second option is likely to take you right back to the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
git am -3 foo.patch
patch -p1 < foo.patch
```

Fix any conflicts manually then remove .rej files.

Then do:

```
git add fixed_conflicted_files
git am --continue
```